# AWS - resize BMP on upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**TASK**

I am trying to write a Lambda function for AWS which upon uploading any given bitmap file to my AWS cloud, the function will read this given bitmap and resize it to a preset size and rewrite it back to the same bucket that it read it from.

**SCENARIO**

My Ruby web-app PUTs a given bitmap file to my AWS bucket which is 8MB in size and approximately 1920x1080 pixels in size.

Upon being uploaded, the image should be read by my Lambda function, resized to 350 x 350 in size and rewritten with the same file name and key location back to the bucket.

**PROBLEM**

I have no experience with NodeJS, and hence I cannot properly write this function myself. Can anyone advise me the steps to complete this task or point me to a similar function which outputs a resized BMP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image resizing is one of the reference uses for Lambda.  You can use the [Serverless Image Resizer](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/serverless-image-handler/), which is a really robust solution, or an older version of it [here](https://github.com/amazon-archives/serverless-image-resizing).

There are literally dozens open source image manipulation projects, that you can find on Github.  A very simple standalone Lambda that supports BMP's out of the box can be found [here](https://github.com/DisruptiveLabs/lambda-thumbnailer/blob/master/index.js).